# C++ sync between two threads using a mutex without using conditional variable

Tags: c++, locking, thread-synchronization, stdmutex

I have one thread that needs to be blocked until something happens in another thread. It sounds very typical and I have this solution.

```
//thread 1
mux.lock();
//send work to another thread
mux.lock(); //will likely block which I want

//thread 2
//get the work sent over from thread 1
//work on it, then
mux.unlock(); //unblock thread 1 - all good
```

This works fine seemingly on Linux and it does not need a conditional var - except C++ standard says it is undefined behavior to acquire the lock in the same thread twice - which I do in thread 1.

Comment: Is the solution above good or I have to involve conditional var?

Answer (score 5):

A standard `std::mutex` cannot be unlocked by a thread other than the one that locked it. It's undefined behavior to try.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock) on `std::mutex::unlock` :

> Unlocks the mutex.
>
> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

For this reason your proposed strategy doesn't work with `std::mutex`.

Comment: Thx.I coded the condition variable solution and it 150% more code than the above one, but I can sleep better at night, :-)
Basically, instead of a single mutex, I added one bool and one condition_variable in extra - put them into a single struct and allocate it once in heap ... you can imagine the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try_lock? You can use spinlock. Sometrhing like:

```
while(mutex.try_lock()) 
    sleep(100);
```

will not crash and will block until first thread unlocks mutex.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock

Comment: try_lock has the same above mentioned limitations as lock - even with spurious false return headache as I read

Comment: So if you want to stick to stdlib you can use recursive_mutex:
[https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex][1]

But it is still not perfect:

`The maximum number of times that a recursive_mutex may be locked is unspecified, but after that number is reached, calls to lock will throw std::system_error and calls to try_lock will return false.`

Answer (score 0):

The best/easiest solution I see is using boost::barrier;
except it is not as flexible - for example you cannot add timeout behavior which is typically needed.